# how do i trigger the javascript event with dropdown and change the values?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a form where the users will have to select the country from the drop down list. as soon as they selects it should activate another drop down list where it should show the states belonging to the country and hence it should process the value from country Id of  element. and as soon as the user selects the states another drop down list  should activate listing the cities belonging to that particular states, and hence so on to areas.

for that i have written the php and html code like this.

```
Select Countries : <select name="countries"><br/>
<?php
foreach($property->getAllCountries() as $countries) 
{ 
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $countries['id']; ?>"><?php echo $countries['name']; ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select><br/>
Select State : <select name="state">
<?php
foreach($property->getStatesFromCountryId($countryId) as $states) 
{ 
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $states['id']; ?>"><?php echo $states['name']; ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

the javascript should automatically insert $countryId from  and populate the states after the user selects it.

i am noob at javascript i would appreciate if someone could guide me how to achieve this?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for bad english.
you should add onchange="showstates()" to select countries and a div to add states of country  to it

```
function showstates()
{
var country=document.getElemtById("countries").value;
if (country=="anywhere")
{
document.getElemtById("statesofcountries").innerHTML='<div>"states list"</div>';
}
}
```

[check this link](http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/)

Comment: what is if(countries==anywhere) i would appreciate if you can explain the code.

Comment: sorry. i edited it. after you select country showstates() is called. it will checks country name and will add states of country

Answer (score 0):

You can always google it up:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/change-dropdown-list-options-values-from-database-with-ajax-and-php.html